# How to minimize a form in C# after showing another?

Tags: c#, winforms

My question is if I open a new form like this:

```
   Admin inst = new Admin();
         inst.Show();
   Form1.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized; ///Doesn't work
```

How do I minimize the form I was on before opening the other one, without having to open another instance of Form1 ? If I use this.WindowState... it minimizes the whole program. IE: Form1

Comment: What does "Doesn't work" mean?

Comment: Error 1 An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property '

Comment: It's hard to answer, without some background explaining what you're doing. Where are you opening the form from? What is Admin? Where is this method running? What is Form1, and where is it created?

Comment: Admin is a Form ie Form1 = new Form1(); Admin = new Admin();

Comment: I think you need to post more of your code, and more background as to what you're trying to do. Otherwise I'm afraid this question is risking being closed as 'unclear what you're asking'...

Comment: Okay I have a different question I got the answer for this one.. How do i access information from Form1 to Form2 ?

Comment: @IceDawg You need to do a search on SO for that question. It has been asked quite frequently and I am sure you can find an answer with out asking another question.

Answer (score 0):

Hide your form first then show the Admin form.

Answer (score 0):

```
this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized
//Show your form here
```

Answer (score 0):

@IceDawg ur question is hard to understand...but r u trying to do this

```
Form2 form = new Form2();
        form.Show();
        this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized;
```